# Searching for a negative idiom. Where a person sacrifices long term for small relief

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What's a negative idiom for a situation where a person sacrifices long term benefit for small, short term relief.

Example:

> I am cold so I cut off pieces of my jacket to start a fire.

Basically inconveniencing, sacrificing something large for a small moment or purpose without hindsight.

Comment: "Sell your birthright for a mess of pottage" perhaps?

Comment: I think you need to add more details. For instance why are you using your jacket to start a fire? because you have nothing else available or what?

Comment: Or "don't throw the baby out with the bath water", as in: don't discard something valuable along with something undesirable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phrase for targeting surface level problems?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197955/phrase-for-targeting-surface-level-problems) Or this:[Word or phrase for someone who does not think far into the future](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254473/word-or-phrase-for-someone-who-does-not-think-far-into-the-future/254475#254475) (eg adopt a short-sighted approach)?

Comment: ... Or [Phrase to describe a 'fix' that doesn't address the underlying issue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346431/phrase-to-describe-a-fix-that-doesnt-address-the-underlying-issue)?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider *[eating the seed corn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eat_the_seed_corn)*:-

> To consume what is meant for investment (Wiktionary)

Answer (score 0):

There is an expression which is not as explicit as what should be what you are looking for but which does come close in the way of expressing it. It is "***live for the moment***" ([Free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+for+the+moment)).

> To focus on the pleasure one can have in the present, without concern for the consequences one may face in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much an idiom, but **short-sighted** or **myopic** are common ways to describe an action or plan that doesn't consider long-term consequences.

You may also try [**shoot [oneself] in the foot**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/shoot-yourself-in-the-foot), though this can be applied to both accidents and intentional actions.

And of course, if you're ok with some comedic effect or a very-low academic context, you could always use **YOLO** which, at this point, can be really any part of speech you want.